# Kendo Grid buttons Tool Tip issue

Tags: c#-4.0, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am facing a tooltip issue. I am writing a common grid component in .cs file(code behind) and I am building the commands as per below:

```
columns.Command(command =>
             {
                 command.Edit().UpdateText("Save my Changes").CancelText("Cancel all").Text("Edit");
                 command.Destroy().Text("Delete for good");
             }).Width(200);
```

When the user moves his mouse over the button, how can i show the tooltip. how do I assign the tool tips for each button? I used htmlattributes, but all buttons got the same tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

Use Title property. 
e.g. col.Command(command => { command.Edit().HtmlAttributes(new { @title = "Edit" }); command.Destroy().HtmlAttributes(new { @title = "Delete" }); });